How to recover a accidentally deleted table in ASP.NET Web API & Entity Framework project with Azure SQL Server?
I accidentally deleted a table manually from my Azure SQL Server database in an ASP.NET Web API & Entity Framework project.
How can I restore it?
Migrations won't update because it thinks the database is up to date, unaware of the deleted table.

Restore the latest backup (prior to the delete) to a different database name. Check that the table is correct. Script the table definition (including all constraints and indexes). Apply that script to the original database. Copy the data.

The way I have done this before, I perform point-in-time restores to new databases selecting different point in time close to the time the table was deleted. You can do that using Azure Portal or PowerShell.
$subscription = "Subscription1"
Login-AzureRmAccount -Subscription $subscription
Get-AzureRmSubscription
Select-AzureRmSubscription -Subscription $subscription

$resourceGroup = Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroupName
$server = Get-AzureRmSqlServer -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup.ResourceGroupName -ServerName $serverName
$database = Get-AzureRmSqlDatabase -ServerName $server.ServerName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup.ResourceGroupName -DatabaseName $databaseName

New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseRestorePoint -RestorePointLabel $restorePointName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup.ResourceGroupName -ServerName $server.ServerName -DatabaseName $database.DatabaseName

Once you find the table on one of the newly created databases as result of the restore operations, you can use Azure Elastic Queries or Azure Data Factory to move the data in the table to the Production or original database.
